# Fully async solution for factory boy style fixtures in FastAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi, fixtures, factory-boy

I really like the [factory boy](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) style of generated factories that can handle things like sequences, complex relationships etc.

For a FastAPI app with fully async database access using factory boy seems likely problematic. There is [dated discussion here](https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy/issues/679) and an [old PR](https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy/pull/803) to add async support that seems stuck.

Is there a good solution for these kinds of fixtures that has full async support?